# Update Database fails. can't find error (FOUND ERROR)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to update a database using this code but it fails every time and I cannot find why the form fails. if someone could help, i would appreciate that alot!!

These are the codes i use to update the DB (these are three files total)

When you go to my editor you will see this screen.(everything works exept the update) it says cannot update data. it doesn't show any other errors.
did i miss something?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start(); // Start the session
$loggedin = $_SESSION['loggedin']; // Are they loggedin?

// They are not logged in, Kill the page and ask them to login.
if ($loggedin != "1") {
die('Sorry your not loggedin, please login to gain acces. <a href="datlogin.php"> Here </a> to login');}

?>

<?php
$host=""; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name=""; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<head>
<style>
div
{
fload:center;
width:1000px;
margin:0 0 15px 20px;
padding:15px;
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<div align="center">
</head>
<img src="http://www.emiclaer.nl/Portals/39/Tuinen.jpg" alt="DTlogo.img" width="880" height="280">
</div>
<body style="margin:15px;">
<div>
Druk op <font color="blue"><u>Update</u></font> om de App te Updaten.<br>
<p></p>
<center>


<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
<tr>
<td colspan="4"><strong>Iphone aanbiedingen.</strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Naam</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Omschrijving</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Prijs</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Promotext</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>URL</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Image URL</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Update</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['naam']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['omschrijving']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['promotext']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['prijs']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['url']; ?></td>   
<td><? echo $rows['iurl']; ?></td>
<td align="center"><a href="updateformthingy.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">Update</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
mysql_close();
?>
</div>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the second screen you will go to

```
<html>
<?php
session_start(); // Start the session
$loggedin = $_SESSION['loggedin']; // Are they loggedin?

// They are not logged in, Kill the page and ask them to login.
if ($loggedin != "1") {
die('Sorry your not loggedin, please login to gain acces. <a href="datlogin.php"> Here </a> to login');}

?>
<?php
$host=""; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name=""; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

// Retrieve data from database
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<head>
<style>
div
{
fload:center;
width:1000px;
margin:0 0 15px 20px;
padding:15px;
border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<div align="center">
</head>
<img src="http://www.emiclaer.nl/Portals/39/Tuinen.jpg" alt="DTlogo.img" width="880" height="280">
</div>
<body style="margin:15px;">
<div>
Vul hier de updates in.<br>
<p></p>
<center>


<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update Iphone App</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><strong>Naam</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Omschrijving</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Prijs</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Promotext</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>URL</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Image URL</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Update</strong></td>
</tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="updateform.php">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="inp_naam" type="text" id="inp_naam" value="<? echo $rows['naam']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="inp_omschrijving" type="text" id="inp_omschrijving" value="<? echo $rows['omschrijving']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="inp_prijs" type="text" id="inp_prijs" value="<? echo $rows['prijs']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="inp_promotext" type="text" id="inp_promotext" value="<? echo $rows['promotext']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="inp_url" type="text" id="inp_url" value="<? echo $rows['url']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
<td>
<input name="inp_iurl" type="text" id="inp_iurl" value="<? echo $rows['iurl']; ?>" size="15">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</center>
<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This Code is what has to Update the database. (i have updated this one to most comments on the page, mysqli and PDO don't work for me.)

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start(); // Start the session
$loggedin = $_SESSION['loggedin']; // Are they loggedin?

// They are not logged in, Kill the page and ask them to login.
if ($loggedin != "1") {
die('Sorry your not loggedin, please login to gain acces. <a href="testlogin.php"> Here </a> to login');}

?>
<?php
$inp_naam=$_POST['inp_naam'];
$inp_prijs=$_POST['inp_prijs'];
$inp_promotext=$_POST['inp_promotext'];
$inp_url=$_POST['inp_url'];
$inp_iurl=$_POST['inp_iurl'];
$id=$_POST['id'];

$host=""; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name=""; // Table name


// Connect to server and select database. 
$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect Host");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE `$db_name`.`$tbl_name` 
      SET `naam` = '$inp_naam', 
          `omschrijving` = '$inp_omschrijving', 
          `prijs` = '$inp_prijs', 
          `promotext` = '$inp_promotext',  
          `url` = '$inp_url', 
          `iurl` = '$inp_iurl' 
       WHERE `$tbl_name`.`id` = '$id'";

$result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);

if (!$result) {
// if successfully updated.
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
} else {
die('cannot update DataBase'. mysql_error());
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

To

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
session_start(); // Start the session
$loggedin = $_SESSION['loggedin']; // Are they loggedin?

// They are not logged in, Kill the page and ask them to login.
if ($loggedin != "1") {
die('Sorry your not loggedin, please login to gain acces. <a href="testlogin.php"> Here </a> to login');}

?>
<?php
$host=""; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name=""; // Database name
$tbl_name=""; // Table name

session_start();

// Connect to server and select database. 
$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect Host");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database
$sql="UPDATE tblProducts
SET naam = '".$_POST['inp_naam']."', 
omschrijving = '".$_POST['inp_omschrijving']."', 
prijs = '".$_POST['inp_prijs']."', 
promotext = '".$_POST['inp_promotext']."',  
url = '".$_POST['inp_url']."', 
iurl = '".$_POST['inp_iurl']."'
WHERE id = '".$_POST['inp_id']."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);

if (!result) {
// if successfully updated.
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
} else {
die('cannot update DataBase'. mysql_error());
}
mysql_close();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you alot for your time!

Mysqli.

```
// Connect to database
$con=mysqli_connect("$host","$user","$pass","$db_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
// Get id from URL bar
  $id=$_GET['id']

// connect to table
$sql="SELECT * FROM `tblProducts` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
// get table information
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Please use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql. Mysql is deprecated currently and removed in php >= 5.5.0. Try to use Prepared Statements to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: Echo $sql;   you should be able to see where things are going wrong i think you have some problems with your ''s

Comment: On the first script you have the head tag inside the body tag.

Comment: Change `mysql_query($conn,$sql);` to `mysql_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysql_error())` and take a look at the error.

Comment: the second page has to send it to the third. the $_GET is used to get the id that is in the URL bar cause of <a href="updateformthingy.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"> this happends in the second page. (first page is just to show information that i retrieved form the database)

Comment: @MarcelBalzer i've done that though it doesnt have any effect, with the code i used in front of . mysql_error()); shows. and the error self doesn't, changing it to die(mysql_error()); will turn it to a blank screen.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the syntax for your query is incorrect. The SQL query should be passed as the first parameter, with the connection identifier as the second, for example:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
```

Secondly, your `UPDATE` query contains invalid characters. You should use backticks to escape field names in MySQL,not quotes. Update your code as follows:

```
$sql="UPDATE `$db_name`.`$tbl_name` 
      SET `naam` = '$inp_naam', 
          `omschrijving` = '$inp_omschrijving', 
          `prijs` = '$inp_prijs', 
          `promotext` = '$inp_promotext',  
          `url` = '$inp_url', 
          `iurl` = '$inp_iurl' 
       WHERE `$tbl_name`.`id` = $id";
```

You'll see that I also removed the erroneous squared brackets (`[]`) as well.

Please be advised that `mysql_*` functions are now deprecated. You should look into [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo). Also be advised that your code is wide open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should learn about sanitizing your input, and in particular, [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Thanks!! im going to give it a shot, would you recommend PDO or MySQLi? or doesn't it really matter.

and editing the  update code didn't help, still same error

Comment: Personally, I use PDO. It's a matter of personal taste I guess, but PDO provides better functionality IMHO.

Comment: Allright im going to take a look. and update my codes to PDO and MySQLi and look what works best. thank you alot!

Comment: nop didnt work.. and only got the update code to PDO yet. Just arrived at work so gonna get to it today.

Comment: nop im not, i cannot use PDO cause it isn't installed on the DB. and my empoler doesn't want to update it cause he doens't use it.. So im stuck with mysql

Comment: Surely you can use MySQLi?

Comment: I can use it now, so ima go back to coding i'll let you know!

Comment: I just went and tried the mysqli, it doesnt work either. blank page.... i have added with "edit" the mysqli code i've used. maybe i'm doing it wrong, maybe i just cannot use it. i really hope it's the first.

Comment: Errm, you're not outputting anything from your MySQLi result?

Comment: oh haha lol this is my fetch form, it didnt work properly so posted it. but got other one working now. + i learned some PDO and MYSQLi

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this **'** is the correct symbol for using with table and column names.

```
UPDATE '$db_name'.'$tbl_name' 
SET 'naam' = ['$inp_naam'], 'omschrijving' = ['$inp_omschrijving'], 'prijs' = ['$inp_prijs'], 'promotext' = ['$inp_promotext'], 'url' = ['$inp_url'], 'iurl' = ['$inp_iurl'] 
WHERE '$tbl_name'.'id' = $id
```

Maybe you wanted to use **`** ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="UPDATE '$db_name'.'$tbl_name' 
SET naam = ['$inp_naam'], omschrijving = ['$inp_omschrijving'], prijs = ['$inp_prijs'], promotext = ['$inp_promotext'], url = ['$inp_url'], iurl = ['$inp_iurl'] 
WHERE '$tbl_name'.id = $id";
```

Remove single quote from column name

Answer (score 0):

This code of yours has some serious security issues. You are writing POST/GET-variables without quoting to an SQL query, which let's users inject SQL into your query (see http://xkcd.com/327/ :)).

For DB interaction I usually use PDOs (http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php).

Your code will look like this:

```
 $sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE '.$db_name.'.'.$tbl_name.' SET naam = ?, omschrijving = ?,  prijs = ?, promotext = ?, url = ?, iurl = ? WHERE '.$tbl_name.'.id = ?');
 $sth->execute(array($inp_naam, $inp_omschrijving, $inp_prijs, $inp_promotext, $inp_url, $inp_iurl, $id));
```

**Edit:** Without PDO this would look like this:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE ".$db_name.".".$tbl_name." SET"
    ." naam = '".mysql_real_escape_string($inp_naam)
    ."', omschrijving = '".mysql_real_escape_string($inp_omschrijving)
    ."',  prijs = '".mysql_real_escape_string($inp_prijs)
    ."', promotext = '".mysql_real_escape_string($inp_promotext)
    ."', url = '".mysql_real_escape_string($inp_url)
    ."', iurl = '".mysql_real_escape_string($inp_iurl)
    ."' WHERE ".$tbl_name.".id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'");
```

Comment: So first line is where and second is where it get its information from?
P.S. great picture haha, i will fix that but also this page is going to be for the compagny i work for, it will be intern only.

Comment: i got it assigned by my employer as a training, and it is going to be used to update the apple iphone app. So I just want it to work before I'm going to focus on how beautiful my code is.

Comment: Okay, so there is now a non-PDO variant :)